# Angular 2 polyfills trouble

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, git

So I had a hard drive failure and lost everything but of course github to the rescue. I recently finished my first Angular 2 project and did a git clone to recover it and every time I try to run ng server I get this error...

`ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'newLine' of undefined
    at Object.getNewLineCharacter (D:\GitHub\sandbox\meadowbrook_acres\angular-src\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:8062:20)
    at Object.createCompilerHost (D:\GitHub\sandbox\meadowbrook_acres\angular-src\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:44978:26)
    at Object.ngcLoader (D:\GitHub\sandbox\meadowbrook_acres\angular-src\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:338:33)
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts`

ERROR in ./src/polyfills.ts
Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'newLine' of undefined
    at Object.getNewLineCharacter (D:\GitHub\sandbox\meadowbrook_acres\angular-src\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:8062:20)
    at Object.createCompilerHost (D:\GitHub\sandbox\meadowbrook_acres\angular-src\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:44978:26)
    at Object.ngcLoader (D:\GitHub\sandbox\meadowbrook_acres\angular-src\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:338:33)
 @ multi ./src/polyfills.ts`

I did an npm install on both the project folder and the angular src folder then did a npm install typings --global after googling this error and still it doesn't allow me to do anything. any other ideas on what I can do?

Comment: What version of the cli are you on, and which version is defined in your package.json? I remember getting similar, odd errors because of version mismatching.

Comment: I used the latest one I did the "upgrade" from the angular 2 github so I have to assume that it is the latest version

Comment: Do you have the repo available so I can have a look?

Comment: sure do here it is

https://github.com/LjCraft12/meadowbrook_acres.git

Comment: Run `ng -v` inside the src folder and outside?

Comment: ok got it 

@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.1
node: 6.10.0
os: win32 x64
@angular/common: 2.4.9
@angular/compiler: 2.4.9
@angular/core: 2.4.9
@angular/forms: 2.4.9
@angular/http: 2.4.9
@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.9
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.9
@angular/router: 3.4.9
@angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.9

Comment: It def seems like a problem with your CLI version - try going through the upgrade route described in the angular-cli repo on github and see if that helps :)